# make a word centered in a line in java

Tags: java

guys i am trying to print an input word in a input line in equilateral traingle and this word should be centered ... here is my code

```
public void draw (){

    int starTosStart = 0;

    for (int rows=1; rows <= getHeight(); rows++)
    {
        String charToPrint = "*";
        String wordToPrint = "";
        if(rows == getRowNum()){
            starTosStart = ( getRowNum() - getTextLabel().length() )/2;
            for(int i=0;i<getTextLabel().length();i++){
            wordToPrint += " "+getTextLabel().charAt(i);
            }
        }

        for (int spaces=1; spaces <= number_of_stars; spaces++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int star=1; star <= rows; star++)
        {
            if(rows == getRowNum()){

                System.out.print(wordToPrint);
                System.out.print(" ");
                break;
            }
            System.out.print(charToPrint);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        number_of_stars = number_of_stars - 1;
    }
    }
}
```

my output is

```
      * 
     * * 
    * * * 
   * * * * 
  * * * * * 
 * * * * * * 
 Z E L D A
```

while the output needed is

```
      * 
     * * 
    * * * 
   * * * * 
  * * * * * 
 * * * * * * 
* Z E L D A *
```

any help please ? thanks you

Comment: If you already get the triangle correctly, what's so hard with the word? Basically it's a triangle with characters instead of stars at the last line.

Comment: my problem is how to be centered and the empty spaces should be stars ??

Answer (score 1):

You already got it, simply change this lines:

```
 System.out.print(wordToPrint);
 System.out.print(" ");
```

By this

```
 System.out.print("* " + wordToPrint + " *");
```

Comment: what if i entered another word of only 2 characters ?/

Comment: this word is input by the user

Comment: you tested it? if your method is correct for a 2 letter word it must print 3 lines of * and the word centered at the fourth... really? With the code you provided it works, but I can't test your `getHeight` methods if you don't publish all the code...

Answer (score 0):

You could treat the word as an array of characters and use the length of that array to "replace" the relevant stars in the last line with the appropriate character from that array.

So basically you'd calculate the offset (where to start replacing the stars) as `offset = number_of_stars - word.length() / 2`  and then use `word.charAt(star - offset)` to get the characters.

I'll add an example if I have time. Just one thought though: how would you handle words that won't fit that last line? How would you handle words of even length in a row that contains an odd number of stars?

**Update:** Example for using `charAt()` but without handling even word length vs. odd number of stars.

```
public void draw ( String word, int height ) {
  int wordOffset = (height - word.length())/2 ;        

  //loop through lines
  for (int row=0; row < height; row++) {
    int starOffset = height - row;

    for (int spaces=0; spaces < starOffset; spaces++) {
      System.out.print(" ");
    }

    for (int star = 0; star <= row; star++) {
      char charToPrint = '*';

      //determine if we're inside the word and if so replace the star with a word character
      if(row == height - 1 && star >= wordOffset ) {                    
        int charIndex = star - wordOffset;
        if( charIndex < word.length() ) {
          charToPrint = word.charAt( charIndex );
        }
      }

      System.out.print(charToPrint);

      //print space if not just printed the last "star" in that line
      if( star < row ) {
        System.out.print(" ");
      }    
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Outputs for "Zelda" and heights 7 and 8:

```
                           *
       *                  * *
      * *                * * *
     * * *              * * * *
    * * * *            * * * * *
   * * * * *          * * * * * *
  * * * * * *        * * * * * * *
 * Z E L D A *      * Z E L D A * *
```